# Conditional classes applied in ng-repeat using $index inconsistent when filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `ng-repeat` which is filtered with an input box. In this list, there are `.active` and `.disabled` items. Everything renders correctly, but when I filter it with a query, the active and disabled classes are messed up because the index of the display changed.

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sam_1421/SeQJb/1/) showing the problem. You see that the second row is highlighted (class `active` added). Now try to type "iphone" in the input box. The second line will be highlighted, even if it's not active.

How can I get around this and have reliable data in my `ng-repeat`?

**[edit]** 
However, the right tag (generated by the `ng-if`) is correctly matched even when filtered (again try with "iPhone")...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some places you use `tags_and_devices[$index]` and in some places you use `item`. `item` points to the actual item in the array that you're ng-repeating through, so, even when filtering, you get the item you expect. I don't fully understand what you want your code to be doing, but I think what you want is to only use `item`.

`tags_and_devices[$index]` uses the index in the `ng-repeat` (not the index of the item in your model) to do a lookup in your model.

Comment: Actually found this problem just after posting, and after testing well yes, that's it! Thank you. I feel dumb.

Comment: @SamuelBolduc You should take a look at my answer about how to fix it, since the reason is kinda obvious.

Comment: @sza what would be the advantages of this vs just using `item`? Using @Jon7 solution works as intended, I see your solution more complex for a simple problem (but I could be wrong)...

Comment: @SamuelBolduc You didn't get it. suppose `items` is [a,b,c,d,e], current $index is 2, so items[$index] is c, after you filter, suppose what you see is [a, d, e], but for the same index 2, you get `c` not `e`. (You really want to get `e`) Jon7's solution is totally wrong. That's why in my solution I am telling you the index should be in accordance to current **filtered** list not the original list.

Comment: @sza I don't think you understand his question. He wants to read the `disabled` property from the actual item that it's associated with. Your solution has him manipulating indexes for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent question. Because every time when the filter is applied, the `$index` will be changed according to the current filtered list.

Here is how to deal with it, assign the filtered list to an variable and then $index matches the data.

```
ng-repeat='item in (filtered_tags_and_devices = (tags_and_devices | filter:{ name: assoc_query }))'
```

And then change the criterion to

```
filtered_tags_and_devices[$index].id
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SVThN/)**</kbd>